# How to use $in operator in embed document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid3

I'm new to MongoID. I have following models:

```
class Vehicle
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  ##
  # Relationship
  embeds_one  :specification
end

class Specification
  include Mongoid::Document

  ##
  # Columns
  field :body,            type: String

  ##
  # Relationship
  embedded_in :vehicle

end
```

In my controller I'm trying to use `$in` operator in `body` field of `specification` /embed document/. How to use `$in` operator in embed document? I tried below code but it's not work.

```
result += Vehicle.where(:specification.matches => { :body.in => param(:body) }) if params[:body].present?
```

Thank you for help :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here but `embeds_one` is just a bunch of wrapping around an embedded Hash so `Vehicle.where('specification.body' => ...)` might be a starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @mu-is-too-short mentioned in his comment, to search in embedded docs you use

```
if params[:body].present?
  result += Vehicle.where('specification.body' => param(:body)).to_a
end
```

please note that `Vehicle.where(...)` returns a [Criteria](http://two.mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html) which is not the objects only the query to be evaluated.

also note that if you want to use specific operators like `in`, `<`, `<=` you have to use the corresponding mongodb operator for example

```
Vehicle.where('specification.body' => {'$in' => param(:body)})  # matches .in
Vehicle.where('specification.body' => {'$lt' => param(:body)})  # matches <
Vehicle.where('specification.body' => {'$lte' => param(:body)}) # matches <=
```